# RSpec - require extra test folder with pure Ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm trying to run the 'rspec' command to run all of my tests, but it is ignoring the 'decorators' folder that I created.

I created a folder called 'decorators' inside of the 'spec' directory.

How could I add this folder to be executed when I run the 'rspec' command int the pure Ruby (without Rails)?

The directory is 'spec/decorators'

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: are your files names ends with `_spec.rb`?

Comment: Put `Dir['decorators/**/*.rb'].each { |f| require_relative f }` into `spec-spec_helper.rb`.